# React Route redirection failed

Tags: reactjs, meteor, routes, react-router

I cant understand why component UserLogout doesn't get rendered while i'm pressing the Logout Link. After clicking /currentroute changes to /logout but the view of /logout doesn't appear. Then comes in onEnter method and route  /logout changes directly to /login.
Are there some other methods except onEnter?

Logout option on user profile

```
 <Link to={'/logout'} >
          <div key={2} style={styles.actionItem} >
            <div style={styles.icon}>
              <LogoutIcon />
            </div>
            <div style={styles.action}>Logout</div>
          </div>
        </Link>
```

Logout Route

```
<Route path='/logout' component={UserLogout} onEnter={this.loggingOut} />
```

onEnter method

```
loggingOut(nextState, replace, cb) {
    if (!Meteor.userId()) { replace('/login'); return cb();}
    console.log(Meteor.userId(),'<<<');

    Meteor.logout(() => {
      replace('/login');
      mixpanel.reset();
      cb();
    });
  },
```

P.S. This way i see the content of /logout but don't get the redirection to /login.

```
<Route path='/logout' component={UserLogout} />
```

Comment: Please explain your issue, not your solution question. I don't understand, di you want to create `React` authentication?

Comment: Hi, nope, after user have pressed on logout button, he should see /logout page, and if conditions are right he will be redirected to /login. Thanx!

Comment: What's version of your `React Router` ?

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"

Comment: At first accept my title edition, your have a tiny mistake to type `React`, for `React Router` version 4 you must use `Redirect` tag for this, and write a action to return user interface to login page.

Comment: I just found out from console that component={UserLogout} doesnt rendering but method onEnter={this.loggingOut} redirecting.

Comment: your case is some different